# php-common conflict when installing php-imap on Ubuntu

Tags: apt

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.4-imap
 php7.4-imap : depends on: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.5) but7.4.15-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 should be installed

$ sudo apt-get install php7.4-common
php7.4-common is up to date (7.4.15-7+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

<sub>(roughly translated the `apt` reply)</sub>

I found similar issues in other posts and so removed some of the obsolete repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; the result is unchanged. Any ideas?

`sources.list` has been modified (probably on an update) in February; `xenial` being replaced by `focal`. Could that be the issue, and if yes: how can I solve it?

---

`sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

---

update: I removed all php7.4 packages and reinstalled them (plus php7.4-imap). That resulted in a downgrade to php7.4-3, but at least it works.

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: Would something like `apt-get update && apt-get install -f && apt-get upgrade  && apt-get install php7.4-imap -y` work ?

Comment: @Paul
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: @Tk421 No it won´t. Same message as before.

Comment: It has been a long time since I last tried it, but upgrading versions, especially LTS versions, tends to result in these kinds of problems, which I'm guessing based on your statement in the question of modifying `sources.list` that is what you did. Have you tried uninstalling the offending packages and reinstalling them? I concluded for myself that a migration to latest version is ultimately less headache than upgrade, but YMMV.

Comment: You have mixed packages of ubuntu 20.04 with packages of ubuntu 18.04. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all the files at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, remove all entries for ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) and re-execute the previous commands.

Comment: @Paul see update